# PHP Pagination with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: Table name below]

[image: OUTPUT]

[image]

I have done this pagination using PHP and SQL. id 11 and 12 is missing in the page 2 module. I cant find out where i am doing the mistake. Please find the source code below

```
<?php
$per_page = 5;
$rec_count = $row['id'];
$total_pages = ceil($rec_count / $per_page);         

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $show_page = $_GET['page']; //current page
    if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
        $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
        $end = $start + $per_page;
    } else {
        $start = 0;
        $end = $per_page;
    }
} else {
    $start = 0;
    $end = $per_page;
}

$page = intval($_GET['page']);
$tpages=$total_pages;
if ($page <= 0)
    $page = 1;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(Id) AS id FROM [Register].[dbo].[RegisData] WHERE DeleteStatus = 1";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql); 
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$rec_count = $row['id'];
$total_pages = ceil($rec_count / $per_page);

$sql1 = "SELECT [Id],[FirstName],[LastName],[ProfilePic],[Gender]
                ,[Email],[MobileNo],[Company],[Designation],[Country],[State],[Address],[City]
                ,[Pincode],[Hobbies],[DietaryHabits],[DeleteStatus] 
        FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RegId) as row 
        FROM [Register].[dbo].[RegisData]) 
        a WHERE row between $start and $end 
        AND DeleteStatus = 1 
        ORDER BY RegId";

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql1);
$z = 1;
for ($x=1; $x<=$total_pages; $x++) {
    echo $x;
}  
?>
```

Please help me where i have done the mistake.

Comment: show your pagination code ! and what was your limit for this because this could be for limit too

Comment: There are serveral issues with your code: a) this is not mysql, replace the tag with `sql-server` b) `row_number` starts with 1, you are using 0 as first row. c) you are getting 6 rows per page (between 5 and 5+5=10 includes the numbers 5,6,7,8,9,10) d) the `if ($page <= 0)`-part should obviously be before calculating `$start/$end` e) if you have rows with `DeleteStatus=1`, your pagination will not work correctly, because the `row_number` includes these. And that last point might be the reason for your actual problem (if your picture excludes `DeleteStatus=1`), so add it in your subquery `a`.

Comment: And I forgot to ask: what is your sql-server version? Sql server 2012 and later supports `OFFSET $start ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your replay :-). Where i am using "row_number" as 0 sir?. I am using 5 rows per page. For deleting the record i used DeleteStatus. The deleted record are "DeleteStatus=0"

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir :-) . I am using Sql server 2012 but in live server it is only Sql server 2008

Comment: You set `$start = 0` and then query `... where row between 0 and 5`, which will give you the 6 rows 0,1,2,3,4,5, but since row_number() starts with 1, your 1st page has 5 rows; page 2 (5...10) has row 5 with "Maria" again. And yes, I meant, `excludes DeleteStatus=0`. So any rows with  `DeleteStatus=0` will mess up your row number, because they will be counted in subquery `a`, but excluded in the condition. Try to run just `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RegId) as row FROM [Register].[dbo].[RegisData]` to check which row numbers your missing rows will get, I suppose they have 11 and 12.

Comment: Sir, I have printed and executed the query in SQL Server, 11 and 12 record is missing.